# python socket : server must send a message before recv

Tags: python, sockets

In socket, I found that if server does not send any message before call recv(), server will be no response, whatever using mutilthread or not.
As the figure shows below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWj4C.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldM67.png)

server.py(Using SocketServer module):

```
def handle(self):
    conn = self.request
#    conn.send('Welcome to server')
    flag = True
    while flag: 
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print 'client:' + data
        if data == 'exit':
            flag = False
        conn.send('AAAAAA')
    conn.close()
```

client.py:

```
client = socket.socket()
ip_port = ('127.0.0.1', 11111)
client.connect(ip_port)

while True:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print 'server:' + data
    send = raw_input('client:')
    client.send(send)
    if send == 'exit':
        sys.exit()
```

I would appreciate it very much if you would help me with it.

Comment: Server is service run on terminal, client can run any idle/editor. Never will be work if run with same idle/editor. Terminal is `OS` app, so create thread by `OS`. `client = socket.socket()` socket can't connect without any definitions ! Read python socket manual or examples before writing a socket scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
# server.py
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "Server received data:", data
    conn.send("Data received at server side") 
conn.close()
```

---

```
# client.py
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
print "Client: " + MESSAGE
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print data
```

---

I think providing a sample code could speak itself.

```
# Expected input:
python server.py
python client.py

# Expected output:
# (server output)
Connection address: ('127.0.0.1', 62136)
Server received data: Hello World!
# (client output)
Client: Hello World!
Data received at server side
```

You could find out your missing component by comparing the code,such as bind().
Hope it help.
With reference to this site: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've already found my missing just because client always waitting for a message from server. so server should send something at fisrt，or client will be blocking and as the title says ''server will be no response"